# custom imports?

Tags: android, import

I see people are doing like this:

```
import com.inducesmile.androidlocationtracking.database.DatabaseQuery;
```

and regards that import, this variable 
`private DatabaseQuery mQuery;` 
turns red.

it's different from something familiar like this:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
```

can someone explain what it is: 
`com`.`inducesmile`.`androidlocationtracking`.`database`.`DatabaseQuery`
 and how do we fix it,

or how do we change it to our own website?
basically, I don't understand how to fix that error. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out. it has a class name DatabaseQuery
and the `com.inducesmile.androidlocationtracking.database` is the package hierarcy, so, just follow the rule, you're good to go